# Handle multiple inputs with React Redux - object spread

Tags: reactjs, forms, redux-toolkit

Actually I'm looking for more elegant way to handle multiple inputs value with react reduxjs toolkit.
Form state is stored in slice.
I'm handling all the inputs with single handler and dispatching separate action/object for each input.

It works just fine, but I'm sure there is a more elegant way, by using spread operator to update the state. But, to be honest, I'm stuck here

Here is my form

```
<form id='personalDataStep' onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <label>Name:</label>
            <input
              type='text'
              placeholder='Your name'
              required
              name='userName'
              value={personalInfoData.userName}
              onChange={handlePersonalInfo}
            />
            {}
            <label>Email:</label>
            <input
              type='text'
              placeholder='Your email'
              required
              name='userEmail'
              value={personalInfoData.userEmail}
              onChange={handlePersonalInfo}
            />
            <label>Phone number:</label>
            <input
              placeholder='Your phone'
              required
              name='phoneNumber'
              value={personalInfoData.phoneNumber}
              onChange={handlePersonalInfo}
            />
        </form>
```

Here is onChange handler

```
const handlePersonalInfo = (e) => {
    dispatch(firstStepData({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value  
    }))
  }
```

And here is the slice

```
const formSlice = createSlice({
    name: "form",
    initialState: {
        formData:
            {
                userName: '',
                userEmail: '',
                phoneNumber: '',
                planName: '',
                planDuration: '',
                planPrice: 0,
                priceMultiplier: 10,
                addons: null,
            }
    },
    reducers: {
        firstStepData(state, action) {
            state.formData.userName = action.payload.userName || state.formData.userName
            state.formData.userEmail = action.payload.userEmail || state.formData.userEmail
            state.formData.phoneNumber = action.payload.phoneNumber || state.formData.phoneNumber
        },
```